# Sort file by one key only

Tags: bash, sorting

I have large log file comprised of input from many sources, with each line prefixed with the hostname. The log is the output of operations happening in parallel across many hosts, so the logs are somewhat jumbled together.

What I'd like to do is sort the logs by hostname and *nothing* else so that the events for each server still show up natural order. The sort docs below seem to imply that `-k1,1` *should* accomplish this, but still result in the lines being fully sorted.

```
   -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of line)
```

I've made a simple test file:

```
1 grape
1 banana
2 orange
3 lemon
1 apple
```

and the expected output would be:

```
1 grape
1 banana
1 apple
2 orange
3 lemon
```

But the observed output is:

```
$ sort -k1,1 sort_test.txt
1 apple
1 banana
1 grape
2 orange
3 lemon
```

Comment: This is probably something that can be done in a few lines of `awk`; perhaps try [unix.se] to pick brains there? [This also might give clues](http://www.thelinuxrain.com/articles/grouping-with-awk) so you have an attempt to show.

Comment: Or [just use the `-s` flag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374067/46316)...

Comment: Actually while I was waiting I made a gross oneliner that added the line number in with awk, sorted that by two keys, and then stripped the line number back out. But `-s` is way the hell better. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4):

`sort -s -k 1,1 sort_test.txt`

The -s disables 'last-resort' sorting, which sorts on everything that wasn't part of a specified key.